# How to use Delphi's AsCurrency to show currency without currency symbol?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to display a currency value in a grid, but I do not want the currency symbol to be shown:

```
if fPreferences.WorksheetFormat = 'Numeric' then
begin
  CurrencyString := '';
  Value := FieldByName('UnitList').AsCurrency;
end else
  Value := CurrToStrF(FieldByName('UnitList').AsCurrency, ffCurrency, 2, langFormat);
```

The problem is that it's still showing the currency symbol. What am I doing wrong here?  I don't think I can use CurrToStrF, because I need the grid to export a number to excel, not a string.  Or, is there any way I can use AsFloat, but have to decimal places? (100.00)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `CurrencyString := '';` will **impact all the following formatting** of currencies when **using the default format** strings and thus should **display** all the currency variants/fields values **without the $ sign**, while **retaining their numeric nature**.

But when you **explicitly** format your currency value with **your own TFormatSettings** langFormat, it has **no effect unless you previously did**:

```
langFormat.CurrencyString := '';
```

Comment: But I'm trying to format the Value that will be a currency, not the value that will be set with CurrToStrF - how can I change the currency value to not display the currency symbol?

Comment: Not sure I understand... The currency symbol is not linked to a currency value but to a FormatSettings, either the default one used by default when not otherwise specified or a specific one like your `langFormat.CurrencyString`. So if your Value is a Currency, it will stay a Currency but will be displayed by default according to the global CurrencyString. If you change it from '$' to '@', your Value will then be displayed like @12.34 instead of $12.34 like before.

Answer (score 2):

Changing ffCurrency to ffFixed should get rid of the currency symbol but there wouldn't be any hundreds separators.

//With separators

sStrVar := FormatCurr('#,##0.00', CurrVar);

Answer (score 0):

a very simple solution would be to change the CurrencyString yourself
and change it back to the original value later.

```
if fPreferences.WorksheetFormat = 'Numeric' then
begin
  CurrencyString := '';
  Value := FieldByName('UnitList').AsCurrency;
end else
  begin
    OldCurrStr := CurrencyString;
    CurrencyString := '';
    Value := CurrToStrF(FieldByName('UnitList').AsCurrency, ffCurrency, 2, langFormat);
    CurrencyString := OldCurrStr;
  end;
```